# How to send packets in ProtocolLib (spigot 1.18.2)

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

i wanted to ask in there is a simple was to send a packet to The Server in minecraft spigot 1.18.2 using ProtocolLib. I haven‘t found a simple answer anywhere.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. It seems to answer to your question. Just, if it doesn't, can you more explain then mare [mre] ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.